# Function to capitalize each word in a column in mysql workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I am trying to create a function to captalize each word in mysql workbench but keep getting a syntax error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'deterministic Begin declare len INT;     declare i INT;          set len = cha' at line

Here is my code:

```
delimiter ;;

CREATE FUNCTION caps_first (input varbinary(100))
RETURNS varbinary(100) deterministic

Begin
    declare len INT;
    declare i INT;

    set len = char_len(input);
    set input = lower(input);
    set i = 0;

    while (i<len) do
        if (mid(input,i,1) = '' or i = 0) then
            if (i < len) then
            set input = concat(
                                left(input,i),
                                upper(mid(input, i+1,1)),
                                right(input, len-i-1)
                            );
            end if;
        end if;
        set i = i+1;
    end while;

    return input;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a stored procedure similar to this about a month ago. Reference [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446093/stored-procedure-to-set-extended-properties-split-column-names-on-capital-lette/51446094#51446094) for the script. If you want to use it directly it'll take a little bit of effort to modify to fit your needs, but it should give you a decent jumping-off point.

I know it isn't straight-up debugging like you're asking for, but comparing code might help you solve your problem.